# How to create a dynamic SOQL based on criteriums?

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I want to retrieve cases based on other objects' records

I.E. I want to retrieve this case:

- Field : CaseNumber
- Operator : Equals to
- Value : 0123

First attempt:

```
public static List<Case> getCases(Id listViewId) {

Critere__c criteres = [SELECT Field__c, Operator__c, Value__c  FROM Critere__c WHERE ListView__c = :listViewId];

String query = 'SELECT Id, <ALL FIELDS> FROM Case WHERE ';

for (Critere__c critere : criteres) {

    query += critere.Field__c;

    query += ' ' + critere.Operator__c + ' ';

    query += critere.Value__c;

    query += ' AND ';

}

// remove last AND

return Database.query(query);
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at fflib and this tutorial: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/apex_patterns_dsl_apply_selector_l_principles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.join` for your filters.

```
String query = 'SELECT ... FROM Case';
String[] filters = new String[0];
for(Critere__c critere: [SELECT Field__c, Operator__c, Value__c  FROM Critere__c WHERE ListView__c = :listViewId]) {
  filters.add(critere.Field__c+' '+critere.Operator__c+' '+critere.Value__c);
}
if(filters.size() > 0) {
  query += ' WHERE '+String.join(filters,' AND ');
}
```

If you want a more complicated setup, you could build some kind of query builder, or use an existing one, such as fflib's [Query Factory](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/sfdx-source/apex-common/main/classes/fflib_SObjectSelector.cls).

Comment: why you declared **filters** as *String[0]* ? this method will return cases' data based on **critere.Field__c+' '+critere.Operator__c+' '+critere.Value__c** ?  I.E : CaseNumber Equals to 0123 but in soql **Equals to** isn't defined

Comment: @Fabien (a) to use `String.join` to optimize the filter generation process, and (b) depending on your operators, you might just use a `Map<String, String>` to map the operator's label to the SOQL version, but not all possible SOQL operators. A proper solution requires several hundred lines of code, far too long for a full answer. Check out the link I provided as an example.

Comment: Can you please tell me which operator are valid in soql ? and how to use *Map<String, String>* to map label to SOQL

Comment: i got this error :  **value of filter criterion for field 'CaseNumber' must be of type string and should be enclosed in quotes**

Comment: @Fabien As I said, a complete solution will require significant effort. You need to understand the data type of the field to understand if you need to use quotes, etc.

Comment: basically all values should be enclosed with quotes , i have used string.valueof but it doesn't worked

Comment: @Fabien Dates, numbers, and Boolean values are not in quotes. If you want to search for multiple values, you need to account for that as well. There is a lot of nuance that goes into building a query. Also, I supposed I should have started off with: why are you doing this? Why not use a standard ListView?

Comment: i'm trying to learn .. Numbers are in quotes , that's why i got that error.

Comment: here's the solution : **filters.add(critere.Field__c+' '+critere.Operator__c+' \''+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(critere.Value__c)+ '\'');**

Comment: but i'm still intereseted *on how to use  map : label to SOQL*

Comment: Can you please answer me , i want to learn .. be humble . i want to know how to use Map to map label to SOQL and if my soql contain " contains" as operator how to change the value .. thanks

Comment: `@Fabien Something like `Map<String, String> opMap = new Map<String, String> { 'contains' => '{0} contains {1}', 'equals' => '{0} = {1}', ...};` Which you then can get the mapping for, and pass it into String.format: `filter.add(String.format(opMap.get(critere.Operator__c), new Object[] { critere.Field__c, critere.Value__c }));` You'd want to know the field's data type, though, so it would be a little more complicated in regards to adding quotes or formatting dates, etc.

Comment: id didnt understand this one  : **Map<String, String> opMap = new Map<String, String> { 'contains' => '{0} contains {1}', 'equals' => '{0} = {1}', ...};** what you aim to do?

Comment: @Fabien String.format. It might help to look at a real project, such as [this one](https://github.com/mjyocca/apex-query). It takes a lot of work to build your own query builder, I strongly suggest you just use something that already exists.